# How to pass an array from Vue frontend to C# backend using axios

Tags: javascript, c#

In the backend in `HelloController.cs`, I have

```
[HttpPatch]
public JsonResponse Patch(IEnumerable<MyObject> myObject)
{
}
```

In the frontend with myObject defined, I have

```
const response = await axios.patch(`http://mywebsite.com/api/Hello`, {
        myObject: myObject,
});
```

However, this results in 500 (Internal Server Error). I then tried doing

```
[HttpPatch]
public JsonResponse Patch([FromUri] IEnumerable<MyObject> myObject)
{
}
```

In the frontend with myObject defined, I have

```
const response = await axios.patch(`http://mywebsite.com/api/Hello`, {
    params: {
        myObject: myObject,
    },
});
```

By doing this, the code actually reaches the backend, but the array is unfortunately empty. I have tried some other combinations such as with [FromBody], but nothing seems to work. Help please.

Comment: what does your payload look like?

Comment: MyObject has a bunch of attributes like `public int helloId { get; set; }`.
In the array, I have JavaScript objects that have all the attributes and they are spelled correctly.
Everything should be good looking at the payload because everything is there, but it is empty in the backend.

Comment: Here is a picture

https://i.imgur.com/SlPpz7z.png

Comment: I can't tell, but you aren't really showing you are sending an array.  it seems you might be sending back an object which has an array as a property, which is why .net would have trouble deserializing it as it would be expecting an array at the top level

Comment: Is it possible to just send an array and not an object? I thought it had to be encased in an object.

Comment: yes.  json at the top level just needs to be an element, which can be a object, array, etc...  see https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the problem!

Comment: awesome, good job!